# "Collapse" and sum data table

Tags: c#

I have a pivoted data table where the columns are locations and there are around 100. The data is a little strange and I'm looking for an easy way to sum (or collapse the data).

```
Date, Location 1, Location 2, Location 3
1/1/2001, 6, 0, 0
2/1/2001, 10, 0, 0
1/1/2001, 0, 5, 0
2/1/2001, 0, 4, 0
1/1/2001, 0, 0, 8
2/1/2001, 0, 0, 2
```

So you can see there are zero fillers so if I was to sum up I'd get unique list of dates and a "collapsed" result that has no zero fillers.

Again, I have about 100 columns and they can't be hardcoded so need a way to sum all these columns dynamically. Is there a trick to do this? Maybe in Linq?

Comment: I'm missing your code. It's not even clear that you are referring to a `System.Data.DataTable`

Comment: I don't have any code. I can manually group by date and sum by each column but that doesn't give me the dynamic and the fact that I have a ton of columns a more dynamic way of doing it. I'm looking for code ideas on how to group/sum when you have a ton of dynamic columns. Am I not able to ask for code ideas on this site?

Comment: So the example data shown above is just a short example to see how the data for 3 of the 100 columns could look like and need to be stored in the table if I get it right that is. Where do you get this data from / how do you get it? I think that is still a useful info to see what options would be available for oyu there.

Comment: Do all columns which you want to pivot start with `Location`?

Comment: @Tim They do not. They are different names of city names.

Comment: @user441521: so what is the identifier of those columns then? Are all columns from the second on "location"-columns?

Comment: Yes. The data is pivoted already but incorrectly pivoted basically because it repeats the dates for each location and 0 fills where the repeated dates are. Those 0's are not really "valid" data. They are just fillers for the repeated dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a combination of loops and LINQ:

```
DataTable pivotedTable = table.Clone(); // same columns, empty
var pivotColumns = pivotedTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Skip(1).ToList(); 
var dateGroups = table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Date").Date);
foreach(var date in dateGroups)
{
    DataRow row = pivotedTable.Rows.Add(); // already added to table now
    row.SetField("Date", date.Key);
    foreach(DataColumn c in pivotColumns)
        row.SetField(c, date.Sum(r => r.Field<int>(c.ColumnName)));
}
```

Here's your sample data:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
table.Columns.Add("Location 1", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Location 2", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Location 3", typeof(int));
table.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2001, 1, 1), 6, 0, 0);
table.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2001, 2, 1), 10, 0, 0);
table.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2001, 1, 1), 0, 5, 0);
table.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2001, 2, 1), 0, 4, 0);
table.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2001, 1, 1), 6, 0, 8);
table.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2001, 1, 1), 6, 0, 2);
```

Output:

```
Date                    Location 1  Location 2  Location 3
01.01.2001 00:00:00      18          5           10
01.02.2001 00:00:00      10          4           0
```

Comment: So I would want the result to still be pivoted. So the columns that would be the final output would be Date, Location 1, Location 2, Location 3. It's just that instead of 6 rows there would only be 2 rows (1/1/2010 and 2/1/2010).

Comment: Yeah, it's about the month that changes (I have Jan and Feb). I think you've got it though! Accepted.

Comment: @user441521: you're right, added sample data and output

Answer (score 1):

If  the first column is always the date and the rest of the columns are always sums you can just iterate the ItemArray on each row

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var sums = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>();

foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < dr.ItemArray.Length; i++)
    {
        sum += (int)dr.ItemArray[i];
    }

    sums.Add((DateTime)dr.ItemArray[0], sum);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. So this doesn't link the column name in any way to the value though right? Maybe I could add these delete the records in the data table and just insert the sums dictionary and it should be in the right column order?